# RegEx que checa se não existe um caractere em uma linha

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Estou tendo dificuldades em montar um RegEx que checa se não existe um caracter em nenhum momento de uma linha após um padrão.

Eu tenho o seguinte log:

```
3/9/18, 17:47 - Pessoa 1: Oi gente!
3/10/18, 22:59 - Pessoa 2 entrou no grupo.
3/10/18, 09:35 - Pessoa 2: Salve!
O que tá rolando de bom?
3/10/18, 09:36 - Pessoa 1: Quanto tempo!
```

Eu preciso descartar as linhas em que existe o seguinte padrão: `data, hora - aviso.`, já que são linhas referentes ao sistema e não a conversa.

Até agora, o RegEx que consegui montar foi o seguinte:

```regex
\d*\/\d*\/\d*, \d*:\d* - (?!\:)
```

Porém o negative lookahead `(?!\:)` só checa o caractere seguinte ao `-`, não o resto da string. O que eu tenho que adicionar no RegEx para forçar ele a checar todo o resto da string?

A demo no regex101 está [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/2dPerp/1).

Comment: Por que as mensagens "Oi gente", "Salve!" e "Quanto tempo!" seriam descartadas? Elas não parecem ser avisos do sistema. Ou você diferencia essas mensagens devido a presença dos dois pontos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui a solução, o RegEx que checa se não há dois pontos após esse padrão é:

`\d+/\d+\/\d+, \d+:\d+ -(?=[^:]+$)`